# Unable to install tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-17.04

Until few months before I was able to download tomcat7 by apt but now it's not working. It is only showing the option to install tomcat 8. I am running this command.

> sudo apt-get install tomcat7

But I am getting error

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package tomcat7

I am using Ubuntu 17. I know how to download, unzip and install it manually but I want it to install from apt.

Comment: Have you updated recently? `sudo apt-get update`? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/388541/e-unable-to-locate-package-update-when-i-try-to-update-my-system-why

Comment: My update and upgrade is working correctly

Answer (score -1):

Install in this way: **sudo apt install tomcat7**. It is for system-wide installation